# python selenium download not working in docker container

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver

My local code can download a file via selenium successfully, but when i run the same code in docker container, seems file does not get downloaded. I don't get any error, but i could not find the file.

I think, using /tmp directory eliminates all permission issues. What is wrong then?

```
my_download_path = "/tmp/test_download/"
print "download path: ", my_download_path
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
      "download.default_directory": my_download_path,
      "download.prompt_for_download": False,  
      "download.directory_upgrade": True,
      "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
        })
chrome_driver = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)
```

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers are [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux)-based and they're minimal so my expectations are:

1. You don't have any GUI there (unless you've installed [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb))
2. You're running your script under [root account](https://geek-university.com/linux/root-account/) (unless you've created a new user and switched to it)
3. You might also need to make your chromedriver executable via [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) command

So add the next lines to your WebDriver initialization routine:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
```

and your test should start working as expected

References:

- [Capabilities & ChromeOptions](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities)
- [How to use Jenkins pipeline to launch Selenium tests](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/jenkins-pipeline-selenium/)
- [Getting Started with Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)
- [Chrome Sandbox](https://www.google.com/googlebooks/chrome/med_26.html)